# React Native's panResponder has stale value from useState?

Tags: react-native

I need to read the value of `useState` in `onPanResponderMove`. On page load `onPanResponderMove` correctly logs the initial value of `0`.

However after I click on `TouchableOpacity` to increment `foo`, the `onPanResponderMove` stills logs out `0` rather than it's new value.

```js
export default function App() {
  const [foo, setFoo] = React.useState(0);

  const panResponder = React.useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onPanResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState) => {},
      onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
        console.log(foo); // This is always 0
      },
      onPanResponderTerminationRequest: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {},
      onPanResponderTerminate: (evt, gestureState) => {},
      onShouldBlockNativeResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {
        return true;
      },
    })
  ).current;

  return (
    <View style={{ paddingTop: 200 }}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setFoo(foo + 1)}>
        <Text>Foo = {foo}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View
        {...panResponder.panHandlers}
        style={{ marginTop: 200, backgroundColor: "grey", padding: 100 }}
      >
        <Text>Text for pan responder</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `useEffect` you can create a new `PanResponder` when `foo` changes. However I'm not sure how performant this is.

```
export default function App() {
  const [foo, setFoo] = React.useState(0);

  const pan = PanResponder.create({
    onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
    onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
    onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
    onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
    onPanResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState) => {},
    onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
      console.log(foo); // This is always 0
    },
    onPanResponderTerminationRequest: (evt, gestureState) => true,
    onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {},
    onPanResponderTerminate: (evt, gestureState) => {},
    onShouldBlockNativeResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {
      return true;
    },
  });

  const [panResponder, setPanResponder] = React.useState(pan);

  useEffect(() => {
    setPanResponder(pan);
  }, [foo]);

  return (
    <View style={{ paddingTop: 200 }}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setFoo(foo + 1)}>
        <Text>Foo = {foo}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View
        {...panResponder.panHandlers}
        style={{ marginTop: 200, backgroundColor: "grey", padding: 100 }}
      >
        <Text>Text for pan responder</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 23):

The pan responder depends on the value 'foo'. `useRef` wouldn't be a good choice here. You should replace it with [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)

```js
const panResponder = useMemo(
     () => PanResponder.create({
       [...]
        onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
          console.log(foo); // This is now updated
        },
       [...]
      }),
     [foo] // dependency list
  );
```

Comment: Finally I understand when to use useMemo. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

**Issue**

The issue is that you create the `PanResponder` once with the `foo` which you have at that time. However with each `setFoo` call you'll receive a new `foo` from the useState hook. The PanResponder wont know that new foo. This happens due to how useRef works as it provides you a mutable object which lives through your whole component lifecycle. (This is explained in the react docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref))

(You can play around with the issue and a simple solution in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions61014169react-natives-panresponder-has-stale-value-from-usestate-wofyn).)

**Solution**

In your case the simplest solution is to update the PanResponder function with the new `foo` you got from useState. In your example this would look like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const [foo, setFoo] = React.useState(0);

  const panResponder = React.useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onPanResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState) => {},
      onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
        console.log(foo);
      },
      onPanResponderTerminationRequest: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {},
      onPanResponderTerminate: (evt, gestureState) => {},
      onShouldBlockNativeResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {
        return true;
      },
    })
  ).current;

  // update the onPanResponderMove with the new foo
  panResponder.onPanResponderMove = (evt, gestureState) => {
     console.log(foo);
  },

  return (
    <View style={{ paddingTop: 200 }}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setFoo(foo + 1)}>
        <Text>Foo = {foo}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View
        {...panResponder.panHandlers}
        style={{ marginTop: 200, backgroundColor: "grey", padding: 100 }}
      >
        <Text>Text for pan responder</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

**Note**

Always be extra careful if something mutable depends on your components state. If this is really necessary it is often a good idea to write a proper class or object with getters and setters. For example something like this:

```
const createPanResponder = (foo) => {

  let _foo = foo;

  const setFoo = foo => _foo = foo;
  const getFoo = () => _foo;

  return {
     getFoo,
     setFoo,
     onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
        console.log(getFoo());
      },
     ...allYourOtherFunctions
  }

}

const App = () => {
  const [foo, setFoo] = React.useState(0);
  const panResponder = useRef(createPanResponder(foo)).current;
  panResponder.setFoo(foo);

  return ( ... )

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're passing `foo` in an attempt to update the existing state. Instead, pass in the previous state and update it accordingly ([functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)). Like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setFoo(f =>  f + 1)}>
  <Text>Foo = {foo}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

To make the current value of `foo` available inside the `onPanResponderMove` handler. Create a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables).

According to the docs:

> The “ref” object is a generic container whose `current` property is mutable and can hold any value

So, with that in mind we could write:

```
const [foo, setFoo] = React.useState(0);

const fooRef = React.useRef()
React.useEffect(() => {
  fooRef.current = foo
},[foo])
```

Then inside the `onPanResponderMove` handler you can access the ref's current value that we set before:

```
onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
  console.log('fooRef', fooRef.current)
  alert(JSON.stringify(fooRef))
},
```

Working example [here](https://snack.expo.io/@jmmarco/functional-updates-inside-panresponder)

More info on stale state handling [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function)

Comment: I added a Snack example. Maybe that helps clarify a bit.

Comment: You're doing something different in that Snack. You're not accessing foo in onPanResponderMove

Comment: I update the Snack example along with answer @Evanss

Comment: Does that Snack work? It doenst seem to drag or log.

Comment: It doesn't drag, I removed that functionality. But it should log perfectly. Try dragging it and you'll see it responds (won't move but it'll respond).

Comment: Now with dragging and logging capabilities. Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/jmmarco/e6e8c5862be492ab871c82a078bc684c) of the entire app file.